# Using Multiple VBOs to place textures at different points on the screen

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, game-engine

I'm currently working on a game using opengl ES for the android platform. My question relates to using 2 vbos each for placing a separate texture at a different point on the screen and mapping it to its corresponding texture coordinates.

```
x,y for screen coordinates followed by the x,y for texture coordinates

{-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
- 1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
  1.0f, -1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
  1.0f,  1.0f, 0.5f, -1.0f};

{-0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
 -0.75f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
 -0.25f, -0.75f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
 -0.25f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f};
```

So basically the 1st VBO represents the 1st texture occupying the complete screen and display only half of it. Similarly the 2nd VBO represents the 2nd texture occupying only a portion of the screen but displaying the complete texture.

Now my question is, how do I render these 2 textures on the screen using only a single glDraw call and a single vertex and fragment shader (my fragment shader takes care of blending the 2 textures, for the portion they intersect)? If that is not possible, what would be the most efficient way of achieving the same?

(Currently my vertex shader sets gl_Position to the 1st position specified by the 1st VBO alone so both the textures are drawn using the 1st VBO.)

Let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be quite easy. If you already managed to put the 2 textures being used simultaneously in the fragment shader all you need to do is create another attribute storing your second texture coordinates. What you then do is set the 2 pointers and bind them to the attributes respectively before drawing and use the second attribute for the second texture in the fragment shader.

This really has nothing to do with the VBO at all. You could even have a single VBO containing both of the texture coordinates and set the second pointer with the offset pointing to the beginning of the second part of the buffer. To continue a bit on how to use the VBO properly in your case you would want to interleave the coordinates in the buffer so the structure of a single vertex would be:

```
{
   position.x, position.y, position.z,
   texCoord1.x, texCoord1.y
   texCoord2.x, texCoord2.y
}
```

Then simply set those as you please but when setting the attribute pointers use the offsets and the stride to achieve the correct result. Maintaining this procedure should increase the performance because of faster data access.

Comment: Ya i've added 2 attributes, but how would i set gl_Position finally based on the texCoord1 and texCoord2?

Comment: I mean, i've added 2 attributes each for the screen and tex coordinates and using the tex coordinates was fine but how do i use the screen coordinates to set gl_Position in my vertex shader?

Comment: In the vertex shader you should compute the second texture coordinates to be relative to the whole shape. For instance to show the second texture only on the bottom half of the shape the texture coordinates would be in range [-1, 1] instead of [0, 1]. Then in fragment shader only use the 2nd texture where the coordinates for it are in range [0,1]

Comment: But wouldn't that be hard coding? Isnt there some way i could automate that based on the screen coords for the respective textures?

Comment: No, you can not do that. The fragment shader is turned around comparing to natural logic. You can imagine the fragment shader asks you "what to do at this location" not the other way around where you say "do something at that point". You need to send enough of information to the fragment shader for you to produce a result you want.

Comment: But i dont get it.Adding this would introduce conditional statements into my shader which is supposedly bad for performance. So do i hence go about creating 2 vertex shaders each for different  vbos?

Comment: You can lose the conditional statements by smartly use functions available in the shader language. For instance you can use a step function to return 0 or 1 and multiply your second texture source color with it so it does not draw at specific coordinates, for instance if you want a coordinate to be drawn only if it is between 1 and 0 you multiply the alpha by step(.0, coordinate)*step(coordinate, 1.0). The result of this product will then be 1 only if coordinate is larger then .0 and smaller then 1.0...